# laravel 7 nothing happens when i click sign up button it seems like event is not triggering

Tags: php, laravel, user-controls, registration

hello and sorry for my bad English ,
can any one help me ? when i try to sign up nothing happens .
i use laravel 7.
every time I click the sign up button, nothing happens and also no errors are showing.

UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web\User;

use Reminder;
use Exception;
use Modules\User\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

class UserController extends AuthController
{

    public $routes = [
        'home'            => 'web.home.index',
        'forgot_password' => 'frontend.forgot.password',
        'reset_password'  => 'web.user.reset-password',
    ];

    public function getLogin()
    {
        $return_url = '';
        if ( request()->has('return-url') )
            $return_url .= request()->input('return-url');

        $data = [
            'authenticate_url'  => route('web.user.authenticate', ['return-url' => strip_tags(trim($return_url))])
        ];
        return view('web.user.login', $data);
    }

     /**
     * getNewAccount
     *
     * @return view
     */
    public function getNewAccount()
    {
        return view('web.user.new-account')->with(['url' => route('web.user.post-new-account')]);
    }

     /**
     * Logout current user.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function getForgotPassword()
    {
        return view('web.user.forgot-password')->with(['url' => route('web.user.post-forgot-password')]);
    }

    /**
    *
    * getResetPassword()
    *
    * @return template
    * @access  public
    **/
    public function getResetPassword($userHashId,$reminderCode)
    {

        try {

            $hashId = hasher($userHashId,  true);
            if ( !$hashId )
                throw new Exception('Wrong user hash key, please check the url carefully.');

            $user = $this->auth->findById($hashId);

            $isReminderCodeExist = Reminder::exists($user);
            if(!$isReminderCodeExist)
                throw new Exception("Reset code is not exists, please retry.");

            return view('web.user.reset-password')->with(['url' => route('web.user.post-reset-password'),
                                                        'code'    => $reminderCode,
                                                        'hash_code' => $userHashId
                                                    ]);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

new-account.blade.php

```
@extends( "layouts.master-login")

@section('content')

<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center ">
    <div class="hero-static col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xl-8 d-flex align-items-center px-sm-0">

        <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-10" style="margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1 bg-white">
                    <div class="block-content block-content-full px-lg-5 py-md-5 py-lg-6">
                        <!-- Header -->
                        <div class="mb-2 text-center">
                            <p> @include('common.logo')</p>
                            <p class="text-uppercase font-w700 font-size-sm text-muted"> {{ __('dcm.new_account')}} </p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END Header -->

                        <!-- Sign In Form -->
                        <form  action="{{ $url }}" method="POST">

                            @if(session('error.message') )
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ session('error.message') }}</span>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-alt {{ $errors->has('username') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  id="username-username" name="username" placeholder="{{ __('dcm.username_placeholder')}}">
                                {!! $errors->first('username', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-alt {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  id="email-email" name="email" placeholder="{{ __('dcm.email_placeholder')}}">
                                {!! $errors->first('email', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-alt {{ $errors->has('first_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  id="first_name-first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="{{ __('dcm.firstname_placeholder')}}">
                                {!! $errors->first('first_name', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-alt {{ $errors->has('last_name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"  id="last_name-last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="{{ __('dcm.lastname_placeholder')}}">
                                {!! $errors->first('last_name', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-alt {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="password" name="password" placeholder="{{ __('dcm.password_placeholder')}}">
                                {!! $errors->first('password', '<span class="text-danger">:message</span>') !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-hero-primary">
                                    <i class="fas fa-plus mr-1"></i> {{ __('dcm.sign_up')}}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <p class="mt-3 mb-0 d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-between">
                                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-block d-block d-lg-inline-block mb-1" href="{{ route('web.user.index') }}" title="{{ __('dcm.sign_in')}}">
                                        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-in-alt mr-1"></i> {{ __('dcm.sign_in')}}
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- END Sign In Form -->
```

routes/web/user.php

```
<?php


// using this pattern to used php artisan route:cache,
// instead of using router closure/grouping.

$userRouteNameSpace = 'Web\User';
$middlewareName     = 'dcm.logged.in';

// UserController
$userController = "{$userRouteNameSpace}\UserController";

// authenticate user
Route::get('user/login', "{$userController}@getLogin")->name('web.user.index');
Route::post('user/authenticate', "{$userController}@postAuthenticate")
        ->name('web.user.authenticate');

// logout user
Route::get('user/logout', "{$userController}@logout")
        ->name('web.user.logout');

// forgot password
Route::get('user/forgot-password', "{$userController}@getForgotPassword")
        ->name('web.user.forgot-password');
Route::post('user/forgot-password', "{$userController}@postForgotPassword")
        ->name('web.user.post-forgot-password');

//  reset password
Route::get('user/reset-password/{hashId}/{resetcode}', "{$userController}@getResetPassword")
        ->name('web.user.reset-password');
Route::post('user/reset-password', "{$userController}@postResetPassword")
        ->name('web.user.post-reset-password');


// create new user account
Route::get('user/new-account', "{$userController}@getNewAccount")
        ->name('web.user.new-account');
Route::post('user/new-account', "{$userController}@postNewAccount")
        ->name('web.user.post-new-account');


// ProfileController
$profileController = "{$userRouteNameSpace}\ProfileController";
Route::get('user/profile', "{$profileController}@getProfile")
        ->name('web.user.profile')
        ->middleware($middlewareName);
Route::post('user/update-profile', "{$profileController}@postUpdateProfile")
        ->name('web.user.update.profile')
        ->middleware($middlewareName);

// update user avatar
Route::post('user/update-avatar/{hashId}', "{$profileController}@postUpdateAvatar")
        ->name('web.user.update.avatar')
        ->middleware($middlewareName);
        
// Verify User

Route::get('/verify','Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser')->name('verify.user');
```

When I click on sign up, nothing happens, it seems like event is not triggering

Comment: what is inside $url?  and can you show postNewAccount() method?

Comment: @Psycho url íts website url and where is postNewAccount()

Comment: in your userController you have this method, don't you? `{$userController}@postNewAccount`... add it to your question

Comment: @Psycho i dont have postNewAccount in my userController

Comment: @Psycho i dont have postNewAccount in my userController

Answer (score 0):

### ***First***

Please try to understand carefully, you have your both routes (`GET` route: `get('user/new-account'` for new-account page and `POST` route: `post('user/new-account'` for getting the values from `new-account` page) for creating a new user and they are ok. Don't change anything here:

```php
// create new user account
Route::get('user/new-account', "{$userController}@getNewAccount")
        ->name('web.user.new-account');
Route::post('user/new-account', "{$userController}@postNewAccount")
        ->name('web.user.post-new-account');
```

### ***Second***

As you said, you don't have the method `postNewAccount()` in your `userController` so you must have one. So add this code inside your `userController` so that you can get the submitted data here:

```php
public function postNewAccount(Request $request)
{
    // you will get your submitted data here
    // you can either dd() or return to see the submitted data

    dd($request->all()); // or return $request->all();
    
    // you can do the rest of the work here
    
}
```

If you successfully get data, then you can do next step like validation or storing data to database there.

***Important note***: your controller names start with small letter which is also problematic. So, change them like `userController` will be `UserController`

***Suggestion***:: Please follow the [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers) documentation for better understanding the codes before trying them

Comment: sorry but i have NewAccount in My UserController and here is ` * getNewAccount
     *
     * @return view
     */
    public function getNewAccount()
    {
        return view('web.user.new-account')->with(['url' => route('web.user.post-new-account')]);
    }`

Comment: sorry this time it's my mistake, i'm editing my answer, check it and try it

Comment: in my answer `getNewAccount` will be `postNewAccount`, I updated it

Comment: thank you , but after that i get this error ``` Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\Web\User\UserController::postNewAccount(App\Http\Controllers\Web\User\Request $request) should be compatible with Modules\User\Http\Controllers\AuthController::postNewAccount(Modules\User\Http\Requests\NewAccountRequest $request) ◀"```

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` add this line in your controller above  `class UserController extends AuthController` this line